# Invalid BACKGROUND_COLOR?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Can anyone tell me why this code is returning an error that says, "invalid color?"

It seems to be referring to the BACKGROUND_COLOR attribute. But I can't figure out why.

```
function myFunction() {
  var bibiDoc = {};
  bibiDoc[DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR] = 0x000000;
  bibiDoc[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Courier New';
  bibiDoc[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = 0x00FF00;
  bibiDoc[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 12;


  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var par = body.appendParagraph("test");

  par.setAttributes(bibiDoc);
}
```

Comment: It's not returning INVALID COLOR. I tested your code and no errors concerning BACKGROUND COLOR.
http://imgur.com/LxBMvIZ

Try copying the color codes into a new script project to see if that's really the cause of errors.

Comment: Try to use a string of instead of an hexadecimal number. (reference: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Hex Code format but don't forget to put it inside quotation marks:

```
 // Define a style with yellow background.
 var highlightStyle = {};
 highlightStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR] = '#FFFF00';
 highlightStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;

 // Insert "Hello", highlighted.
 DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().editAsText()
   .insertText(0, 'Hello\n')
   .setAttributes(0, 4, highlightStyle);
```

And a here's a list of [Hex Codes](http://cloford.com/resources/colours/500col.htm) you can try.